# Ports busy while running application on tomcat

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, tomcat

Hi i am trying to run a application through Tomcat v7.0 in eclipse indigo .
Whenever I run it it gives me the error ports (8005,8080,8009) are busy 
I tried To

a)Shutdown the system, which will automatically free the ports.
 B)Change the ports 8001,8080,8009 from server.xml file ,I changed it to (8015,8089,8019)
 C)Execute the shutdown.bat file ,and restarting eclipse .

Nothing is working same error again and again ,please help i am at my wits end !

Comment: looks like it is trying to start twice.  If you are starting Tomcat externally you did not need to start again in Eclipse

Comment: so when you changed the ports, did you get an error message about those new ports, or did it not have an impact?

Comment: close Eclipse and then open the task manager and kill all java and/or javaw processes. or use netstat -abv to find out which program is using these ports and then stop it using task manager or kill method

Comment: Are you sure you don't run a standalone tomcat at startup ? Start your system and try to visit http://localhost:8089 to check it out.

Comment: Nope i am sure i am not running it twice , i checked using localhost:8080  .  Before I start it on eclipse it gives me page not found ,after starting i get http error 404

Comment: After changing the port numbers in the server.xml the new port numbers are displayed in the error message

Comment: And after i close eclipse there are no java or javaw processes in the processes tab of task manager